# How to make query from multi-dimensional array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have multidimensional array.

```
$array = [
    "player" => [
        "@attributes" => [
            "id" => 0,
            "avatar" => "MALE"
        ],
        "scenarios" => [
            "scenario" => [
                0 => [
                    "@attributes" => [
                        "id" => 1,
                        "attempts" => 1,
                        "score" => 7,
                        "completed" => 1,
                        "time" => "00:00:10"
                    ],
                    "badges" => "4,1"
                ],
                1 => [
                    "@attributes" => [
                        "id" => 2,
                        "attempts" => 4,
                        "score" => 0,
                        "completed" => 0,
                        "time" => "00:00:10"
                    ],
                    "badges" => "3, 4"
                ],
                2 => [
                    "@attributes" => [
                        "id" => 3,
                        "attempts" => 2,
                        "score" => 10,
                        "completed" => 0,
                        "time" => "00:00:10"
                    ],
                    "badges" => "2, 2"
                ],
                3 => [
                    "@attributes" => [
                        "id" => 4,
                        "attempts" => 5,
                        "score" => 30,
                        "completed" => 0,
                        "time" => "00:00:10"
                    ],
                    "badges" => "1,1"
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

I have to insert this data into database.

I tried this code

```
outputValue($array);
          function outputValue($array){

            foreach($array as $key => $value){

              if(is_array($value)){

                  outputValue($value);

                continue;

              }
              else{

                 queryFire($array);

            }

          }
    }      
          function queryFire($array){
              global $id, $attempts, $scores, $time, $lastElement;

               foreach($array as $key => $value){

                switch ($key){
                   case 'id': 
                       $id = $value;
                   case 'attempts':
                        $attempts = $value;
                   case 'score': 
                       $scores = $value;
                   case 'time':
                        $time = $value;

                  }

                }
                   echo $query = "INSERT INTO `tbluserscenescores`(`suid`, `completed`, `score`, `attempts`)VALUES('$id', '$attempts', '$scores', '$time')";
echo '<br>';

          }
```

But it gives me

```
INSERT INTO `tbluserscenescores`(`suid`, `completed`, `score`, `attempts`)VALUES('0', '0', '0', '0')
INSERT INTO `tbluserscenescores`(`suid`, `completed`, `score`, `attempts`)VALUES('0', '0', '0', '0')
INSERT INTO `tbluserscenescores`(`suid`, `completed`, `score`, `attempts`)VALUES('1', '1', '7', '00:00:10')
INSERT INTO `tbluserscenescores`(`suid`, `completed`, `score`, `attempts`)VALUES('1', '1', '7', '00:00:10')
INSERT INTO `tbluserscenescores`(`suid`, `completed`, `score`, `attempts`)VALUES('1', '1', '7', '00:00:10')
INSERT INTO `tbluserscenescores`(`suid`, `completed`, `score`, `attempts`)VALUES('1', '1', '7', '00:00:10')
INSERT INTO `tbluserscenescores`(`suid`, `completed`, `score`, `attempts`)VALUES('1', '1', '7', '00:00:10')
INSERT INTO `tbluserscenescores`(`suid`, `completed`, `score`, `attempts`)VALUES('1', '1', '7', '00:00:10')
INSERT INTO `tbluserscenescores`(`suid`, `completed`, `score`, `attempts`)VALUES('2', '4', '0', '00:00:10')
INSERT INTO `tbluserscenescores`(`suid`, `completed`, `score`, `attempts`)VALUES('2', '4', '0', '00:00:10')
INSERT INTO `tbluserscenescores`(`suid`, `completed`, `score`, `attempts`)VALUES('2', '4', '0', '00:00:10')
INSERT INTO `tbluserscenescores`(`suid`, `completed`, `score`, `attempts`)VALUES('2', '4', '0', '00:00:10')
```

I dont want that... i want query to be executed once. not repeated.

Result should be

```
`INSERT INTO `tbluserscenescores`(`suid`, `completed`, `score`, `attempts`)VALUES('0', '0', '0', '0')    
    INSERT INTO `tbluserscenescores`(`suid`, `completed`, `score`, `attempts`)VALUES('1', '1', '7', '00:00:10')
    INSERT INTO `tbluserscenescores`(`suid`, `completed`, `score`, `attempts`)VALUES('2', '4', '0', '00:00:10')
```

Can i write query outside of foreach loop or any other technique?

Comment: please indent your array... is unreadeable

Comment: you shouldn't be doing that anyways. use a prepared statement and placeholders. you compile that statement ONCE, then execute it as many times as you have data for it. and your `case` statement lacks `break;`, so you're going to be assigning a bunch of garbage into your variables.

Comment: What about JSON-Functions?

Comment: @YerkoPalma check now

Comment: @MarcB : i just want to know is it correct logic or not? if not what should i do?

Comment: in your insert query you have this: `suid`, `completed`, `score`, `attempts`, but your values show this: `'1', '1', '7', '00:00:10'` ,  wouldnt `attempts` be an integer value? you are feeding it the `time` value instead. Which one is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take your array, and just do a simple iteration like this:

```
$q = "INSERT INTO `tbluserscenescores`(`suid`, `completed`, `score`, `attempts`) VALUES ";
foreach ($array["player"]["scenarios"]["scenario"] as $key => $value) {
    $v = $value["@attributes"];
    $q .= "(`{$v['id']}`, `{$v['completed']}`, `{$v['score']}`, `{$v['attempts']}`),";
}
echo rtrim($q, ',');
```

**Result:**

```
INSERT INTO `tbluserscenescores`(`suid`, `completed`, `score`, `attempts`) 
VALUES (`1`, `1`, `7`, `1`),
       (`2`, `0`, `0`, `4`),
       (`3`, `0`, `10`, `2`),
       (`4`, `0`, `30`, `5`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tryout following code. Here I'm trying to append the string in variable

> $query

in single insert. So DB will be accessed only one time.

```
$query = "";    

outputValue($array);
function outputValue($array){

    foreach($array as $key => $value){

        if(is_array($value)){

            outputValue($value);



            continue;

        }else{

            queryFire($array);

        }

    }
}      
function queryFire($array){
    global $id, $attempts, $scores, $time, $lastElement;

    foreach($array as $key => $value){

        switch ($key){
            case 'id': 
            $id = $value;
            case 'attempts':
            $attempts = $value;
            case 'score': 
            $scores = $value;
            case 'time':
            $time = $value;

        }

    }
    if($query=="")
    {
        $query = "INSERT INTO `tbluserscenescores`(`suid`, `completed`, `score`, `attempts`)VALUES('$id', '$attempts', '$scores', '$time')";
    }
    $query .= ",('$id', '$attempts', '$scores', '$time')";


} 
echo $query;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the first part of the query (INSERT INTO `tbluserscenescores`(`suid`, `completed`, `score`, `attempts`)VALUES) and add this to a string.

Then append the values via a loop to generate a single (albeit massive) SQL query.

```
<?php

outputValue($array);
          function outputValue($array){

            foreach($array as $key => $value){

              if(is_array($value)){

                  outputValue($value);

                continue;

              }
              else{

                 queryFire($array);

            }

          }
    }      
          function queryFire($array){
              global $id, $attempts, $scores, $time, $lastElement;


              $query = "INSERT INTO `tbluserscenescores`(`suid`,     `completed`, `score`, `attempts`)VALUES";

               foreach($array as $key => $value){

                switch ($key){
                   case 'id': 
                       $id = $value;
                   case 'attempts':
                        $attempts = $value;
                   case 'score': 
                       $scores = $value;
                   case 'time':
                        $time = $value;

                  }

                    $query .= "('$id', '$attempts', '$scores', '$time'),";

                }

            echo $query;

          }   
?>
```

Comment: Oops, I misread the original code.

The logic however is to rather than generate a single query/set of values for each insert statement is to append the main query with additional VALUES so you end up with something like this:

    `INSERT INTO `tbluserscenescores`(`suid`, `completed`, `score`,`attempts`)
    VALUES('0', '0', '0', '0'),('1', '1', '7', '00:00:10'),('1', '1', '7', '00:00:10'),('1', '1', '7', '00:00:10'),('1', '1', '7', '00:00:10'),('1', '1', '7', '00:00:10'),('1', '1', '7', '00:00:10'),('2', '4', '0', '00:00:10');`

Then run that single query